# Custom placeholders for git archive export-subst

Tags: git

I am trying to use the gitattributes option `export-subst` to update a copyright message in files exported using `git-archive`.  Including something like `$Format: Copyright (c) ACME Inc 2013 - %cd $` results in the string `Copyright (c) ACME Inc 2013 - Fri Mar 7 10:26:40 2014 +1100` being included in the file.

Close but, as they say, no cigar!  What I want to end up with is `Copyright (c) ACME Inc 2013 - 2014` but there isn't a placeholder which will just give me the year.

Is it possible to customise the placeholders `git-log` (and, by extension, `git-archive`) uses?  Or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: I know this does not answer your question, but I must note that what you want to do is not a good idea. People who are really anal about their copyright—like the FSF—[point out](https://www.gnu.org/prep/maintain/html_node/Copyright-Notices.html) that what you have in your copyright notice is not a _range_ of years but a _list_, so _e.g._ if you haven’t made any non-trivial changes in 2014 then writing “Copyright 2013–2015” constitutes a false legal claim. I know this is frequently and commonly flouted, but this doesn’t make it any less true.